# node red insert a value into mysql database

Tags: mysql, node-red

I'm new on node-red,
I have to enter the value of a variable in a mysql database.
The value of the variable comes from a PLC that I have connected. The variable name is : TEMPO (type integer).
I used a s7 node, into the node-red flow, that reads the values of a variable (TEMPO) come from an S7 PLC (Siemens).
I inserted a function block that contains the following query:

```
msg.topic = "INSERT INTO table2 (TempoStop) VALUES ('" + TEMPO + "')";
return msg;
```

It doesn't work because TEMPO variable value insert into mysql database is : undefined
How should TEMPO variable be declared in the function block to be used in the query?

Comment: You need to edit the question to explain what the data looks like coming outof the s7 node, but basically you will need to probably replace `TEMPO` with `msg.payload` or some sub field of `msg.payload`

Comment: if TEMPO is indeed an integer and the TempoStop field is defined as integer (or long) you don't need the single quote round the value in the SQL as quotes are used for text but not required for numbers